# Jest mock - how to spy on a function, within a function, within a hook within an ES module?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, jestjs, mocking

I have this module that I want to mock:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react'

const SomeContext = createContext({
  set: () => null,
  reset: () => null,
})

export const useSomeContext = () => useContext(SomeContext)
```

... and here is how it is used in a custom react hook:

```
import { useSomeContext } from './someContext'

export const useCustomHook = () => {
  const { reset, set } = useSomeContext()
  useEffect(() => {
    set()
    return reset
  }, [reset, set])
  ...
}
```

I am trying to test that the function `set` is called when the `useCustomHook` component renders. Here is my attempt at writing such a test:

```
import * as useSomeContextModule from '../someContext'
import { useCustomHook } from '../useCustomHook'

const mockReset = jest.fn()
const mockSet = jest.fn()

jest.mock('../someContext', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../someContext')
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    useSomeContext: jest.fn(() => ({
      reset: mockReset,
      set: mockSet,
    })),
  }
})

test('set method is called when useCustomHook renders', () => {
  useCustomHook()
  expect(mockSet).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

But, i get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reset' of '(0 , _index.useSomeContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

```
   7 |
   8 | export const useCustomHook = () => {
>  9 |   const { reset, set } = useSomeContext()
```

Comment: How do you set `reset` and `set`? Where is your context provider? You need `render` fn from `@testing-library/react` and wrap your target component with the context provider otherwise `useCustomContext` has no idea what `set` or `reset` is.

Comment: @n1md7 I have edited the question to show the value of `SomeContext`. I'm not sure I need `render` as this is not a component I am testing - it is a hook. As I am trying to mock `useSomeContext` I don't see how I need a provider.

Comment: Well, it uses `useEffect` and without React context it will fail. Or you need to mock that too which will be pointless. You still need to render. Check this [lib](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/basic-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `jest.mock` I used `jest.spyOn`:

```
import * as useSomeContextModule from '../someContext'
import { useCustomHook } from '../useCustomHook'
import { renderHook, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'

const mockReset = jest.fn()
const mockSet = jest.fn()

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(useSomeContextModule, 'useSomeContext').mockReturnValue({
      reset: mockReset,
      set: mockSet,
    })
  })

test('set method is called when useCustomHook renders', () => {
  renderHook(() => useCustomHook())
  expect(mockSet).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
})

test('reset method is called when useCustomHook unmounts', async () => {
  renderHook(() => useCustomHook())
  await cleanup()
  expect(mockReset).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
})
```